# Ethernet Connection not working on Ubuntu 14.04 (with Windows 10 dual boot)

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, networkmanager

I've dual booted Windows 10 (first) with Ubuntu 14.04. The ethernet works fine when logged into Windows, but when I log into Ubuntu, The Connection Icon (right on the top tray) shows the wireless icon, and it's searching for wireless connections (I have no wireless connections configured so this icon shouldn't even show up, no?). I click on it and it sees the ethernet connection. I click on the ethernet and it just closes the dropdown and just continues searching for wireless connections as if I never clicked it.

Tried pinging google and it says "Unknown host google.com" so there's a disconnect, but no idea what it could be. I know there are multiple threads that deal with this (No wired connection on Ubuntu/Windows dual boot) online but none with my specific issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The wireless icon shows if you have a wireless card connected. I can hide it by right clicking on it and uncheck **Enable Wi-Fi**

Maybe NetworkManager isn't managing the connection. If it's the case see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed) page.

Try to remove the current profile for your Ethernet connection and create a new one. It can be any wrong configuration.

Comment: There are no wireless connections for me to disable because I haven't configured any (and I also don't have a wireless card). The wireless icon is just there and it's doing it's little search animation. I've also tried removing the ethernet connection and adding it back in a few times to no avail.

Comment: @jasonaburton That's awkward if you don't have a wireless card. What `ip link` gives you?

Try a live cd and see if the same issue occurs

Comment: eth0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether

Comment: Also, the issue does happen on the live cd as well.

Comment: @jasonaburton try disabling NetworkManager and use dhcpd on eth0 or install wicd and try with that

Comment: How do I use dhcpd on eth0?

Comment: At the moment I don't access to a Ubuntu machine, so you may need to adapt the commands.
`sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager`
`sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@eth0.service`

This commands are for ArchLinux, like I said, at the moment I don't have access to a Ubuntu machine

Comment: You can also try wicd, I think that uses dhcpcd as a backend. `supo apt-get install wicd`